# jQuery - tr tag not appending

Tags: jquery

I want to append the tr tag with the class name 'tests' at the end of these lines of code that are in the loop, but it does not append the tr tag. Where am I missing?

```
order_items.forEach((element,v) => {

var html = '<input type="hidden" id="orderSku'+[v+1]+'" value="" >';
html += '<input type="hidden" id="orderName'+[v+1]+'" value="" >';
html += '<tr>';
html += '<td>';
html += '<div class="form-check" >';
html += '<input class="form-check-input shipMode'+[v+1]+'" id="shipModes" name="checkId" type="checkbox" >';
html += '</div>';
html += '</td>';
html += '<span id="skuAndName'+[v+1]+'"></span>';
html += '</td>';
html += '<td id="orderItemUnitPrice'+[v+1]+'"></td>';
html += '</tr>';
html += '<tr class="tests'+[v+1]+'"></tr> ';
});
```

Comment: What "doesn't work" about it?  Where do you ever observe the result of this `html` variable?  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem and indicate specifically what problem you are observing?

Comment: sorry for about that. i updated my description

Comment: There won't be a class name with "tests" because you are appending [v+1] to it.

Have you tried this only?
```html += '<tr class="tests"></tr> ';```

Comment: It [works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/pbfth4gL/) in the sense that the resulting string does indeed contain the appended value in that last line of code.  Though it's of course worth noting that if, in your actual code, you are trying to use this `html` variable to update the DOM then it's going to alter the resulting structure because the HTML you're building is very invalid.

Comment: So you create a HTML variable, and then ... do nothing with it and start your next iteration, that overwrites this HTML variable with another content. What is the purpose of that? Furthermore, `input` and `tr` elements cannot be siblings in valid HTML.

Answer (score -1):

You keep overwriting your html variable with invalid HTML

This will work better. At least it creates valid HTML

Also I moved the counter to the shipmode ID instead of the class

```js
const html = order_items.map((element, i) => `<tr>
  <td class="form-check"><input type="hidden" id="orderSku${i+1}" value="" /><input type="hidden" id="orderName${i+1}" value="" />
<input class="form-check-input shipMode" id="shipModes${i+1}" name="checkId" type="checkbox" />
  <span id="skuAndName${i+1}"></span></td>
  <td id="orderItemUnitPrice${i+1}"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="tests${i+1}"></tr>`).join("");
```